# Graph Theory: Graphs whose Scores are Arithmetic Sequences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Do graphs exist such that their scores (sorted sequence of vertex degrees) are in an arithmetic sequence?

I believe the answer is no. But I am having trouble reasoning rigorously.

For example if the first vertex had a degree $n$, the second $n + m$, the third $n + 2m$, each additional vertex will require $m$ incoming edges. Which would increase the degrees of the existing vertex.

Comment: So you have any restriction on the initial value $n$ ? on the step $m$ ? on the length ?

Comment: And more importantly, do you require simple graphs or do you allow multiple edges

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Tell him that the Graph is simple and the only restriction is on the step and it is that it's non zero. The sequence can be any length

Answer (score 2):

For a given degree sequence, we'll call it *feasible* if there exists a graph with this sequence.

**Loops**

First, note that if you allow loops, any degree sequence is feasible. So we'll assume that we fordid them in our graph.

**Simple graphs**

Suppose that your graph is simple. Note that for any degree sequence $d_1\leq d_2 \leq \ldots \leq d_n$, for it to be a feasible degree sequence, we need the basic requirement that $d_n \leq n-1$ (on a graph with $n$ vertices, this is the maximum degree feasible for a simple graphs).

If we want a non-trivial arithmetic progression (with strictly positive step), the only possible one would be $(0,1,2,\ldots,n-1)$. But note that this sequence is not feasible as the last vertex needs to be connected to all others, but the first one is isolated.

Therefore the only possible feasible degree sequence are the trivial arithmetic progressions $(r,r,r,\ldots)$ representing a $r$-regular graphs.

**Multi-edges**

If you allow multi-edges then yes, you mind find some graphs. For instance, the following graph (where the caption for each edge represents the number of multiedges) has for degree sequence $(n_0,n_0+s,n_0+2s,n_0+3s)$
[image]